# Opening Excel with COM displays purple llamas?

Tags: python, excel, com, pywin32

I have this line of code:
     xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")

This works fine when I run the script.

However, I exported the python script to be an exe with py2exe, and after running the exe, it gives this error:

```
KeyError: '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
```

All I did was:

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['xerxes2excel.py'])
```

Comment: It would help to see the py2exe setup configuration you use. There are known issues with using COM with py2exe. See this webpage for example: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/IncludingTypelibs

Comment: I added my setup.py in my question, it is very simple.

Comment: Definitely check out the webpage I linked to in my earlier comment. It describes additions you can make to both your setup.py and your script that should hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: I tried it but it says that typelibs cannot be found. However, since this is internal software and I can guarantee certain rqeuirements on the user's environment, I just changed my code to use Dispatch instead of EnsureDispatch and it worked.